# Autoconvolution-type Integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics, convolution

I have an integral of the type
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(y)f(y-x_1)f(y-x_2)\cdots f(y-x_n) \text{d}y
\end{align}
where $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}$ is a function such that $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^d}\frac{|f(x)|}{1+|x|^{d+\varepsilon}}\leq C$ for some $C>0$.
What I am interested in is the asymptotic behaviour of the integral above. In the case $n=1$ it follows that the autoconvolution of $f$ with itself has the same asymptotic behaviour as $f$, but starting at $n=2$ I can only find a bound of the type
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(y)f(y-x_1)f(y-x_2)\text{d}y \leq \begin{cases}B\, f\ast f(x_1-x_2) \\
B\, f\ast f(x_1) \\
B\, f\ast f(x_2)
\end{cases}
\end{align}
which does not really help me as the bound grows like $B^n$ for $n\to\infty$. I am thankful for any kind of hints of where I might find integrals of this type or how to handle this.